# Decreasing $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ tending to $0$ at $∞$ not convex beyond any point?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, monotone-functions

Given a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ differentiable and strictly decreasing such that $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$, I am looking to find out whether or not there exists an $x_0$ such that $f$ is convex on $(x_0,\infty)$. My guess is that the statement is not true but I can't find a counterexample.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit**: added additional term to make the function actually decreasing. The idea remains the same.

Consider something like $$\frac1x + \frac{\sin(x)}{x^2}+ \frac{4 \sin^2(x/2)}{x^3}.$$  Notice how it keeps wiggling all the way down.  [Here](http://wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+1%2Fx+%2B+sin%28x%29%2Fx%5E2+%2B4+sin%28x%2F2%29%5E2%2Fx%5E3+from+100+to+120) is its graph from $100$ to $120$ to give an impression.

Comment: Is this decreasing for all reals?

Comment: @martycohen if it is not, you can replace it with something simple on the "prefix" e.g if x > 100, it's this function, and if x < 100 it's just linear (with coefficients to make it continious and differentiable

Comment: @martycohen It is not. Thanks for pointing this out. I’ll fix it in a moment.